# How to distinguish the gerund with the object and the -ing form in the meaning of the adjective

Tags: gerunds, present-participles, ing

I read this in Wikipedia: "The program becomes modal, switching between interpreting commands from the keyboard or passing keystrokes on as data to be processed."

The word **interpreting** makes me confused. If it is an adjective, then it has an active form. But then there is a mismatch - the **commands** are interpreted. But it sounds like they are interpreting something.

It can also be a gerund with its own object. For example: Smoking cigarettes is bad for you. How can we distinguish between these two cases?

Comment: "Interpreting" is a verb heading the non-finite clause "interpreting commands from the keyboard", which functions as complement of the preposition "between".  It's clearly a verb since it has a direct object, "commands from the keyboard". And though like most non-finite clauses,it is subjectless, we _understand_ the subject to be "the program". In "Smoking cigarettes is bad for you", again "smoking" can only be a verb since it has "cigarettes" as direct object. Nouns do not take direct objects!

Comment: Thank you, now I am more confident in such constructions.

Comment: @BillJ: I think Martin's point here is this: if you disregard semantics, *interpreting* could be read as an attributive participle modifying the noun *commands*. Of course that is semantically impossibly, but syntactically—if I may be so simplistic—, it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a gerund here. But, as you say, it could have been a participle/adjective in this case, except that the meaning clearly shows that it must be a gerund.

So this may cause ambiguity in cases where the meaning isn't entirely clear. Writers should be aware of this possible ambiguity and avoid it by recasting ambiguous sentences.

Comment: The only way is to look at the meaning that these words form, thank you.